# Firebase Notification not received when device come offline to online or non-running app runs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase cloud notification can not arrive when a device is offline and then comes online after the notifications sent. And also when the app is not running and runs after.

Suppose

1. I sent notification from console. (At this time device is offline)
2. Now when I connect device to Internet the notification cannot arrive.
3. case 2 when app is not running or force-stopped, and then if app is launched the notification doesn't arrive.

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise notifications should be delivered to an offline device coming online 4 weeks after the message was initially sent. Whether your app is running or not should not affect the delivery of the notification. How are you sending the notifications?

Comment: i m using firebase notification console to send!

Comment: When you send from the console the confirmation dialog shows you the time to live of the message. Which is 4 weeks by default. What version of Google Play services is running on the device?

Comment: @ArthurThompson, you mention: "notifications should be delivered to an offline device coming online 4 weeks after the message was initially sent". Does that mean exactly 4 weeks since the time it was sent, or does FCM continually try notifying the client for up to 4 weeks?